# Connecting to mysql with NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

It's been 6 hours since I got stuck on a login topic on a remote mysql server

NodeJs code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); 

//Config Mysql
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "serv",
    user: "root",
    password: "admin",
    database: 'test',
});

//Connection Mysql
con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

But i have this error :

```
Error: Packets out of order. Got: 1 Expected: 0
    at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (L:\Code_Dev\Test\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:470:15)
    at Parser.write (L:\Code_Dev\Test\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:33:29)
    at Protocol.write (L:\Code_Dev\Test\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (L:\Code_Dev\Test\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (L:\Code_Dev\Test\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (L:\Code_Dev\Test\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (L:\Code_Dev\Test\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (L:\Code_Dev\Test\Test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (L:\Code_Dev\Test\Test\server.js:15:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER',
  fatal: true
}
```

Mysql server TCP configuration :
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Could you help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [protocol packets out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140902/protocol-packets-out-of-order)

Comment: Thanks, I just changed but nothing more
+-----------------------------+
| @@global.max_allowed_packet |
+-----------------------------+
|       524288000 |
+-----------------------------+